# Steps for setting up HTTPS using elastic beanstalk with a load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, elastic-beanstalk

I have recently used AWS elastic beanstalk to migrate my parse application server. Everything is working well with just plain HTTP, but I need more security so I've tried diving into the AWS documentation for setting up HTTPS with my server.

My goal is to have a scaleable server using a load balancer which protects all parameters in my API calls.

What I've done:

1. Purchased a domain name from Namecheap.
2. Setup a CNAME alias in Namecheap to point to the DNS of my load balancer
    [image: management in namecheap]
3. Created a certificate using AWS Certificate manager for this purchased domain name
4. Added a load balancer in the network tier of my beanstalk instance 
   [image: I've turned off the HTTP port because I only want the api to be called with HTTPS]
5. Created a Route 53 Hosted Zone for this domain and added a record set 
   [image]

Now I'm not sure how to use or test this. Before I had a load balancer I would just input the DNS name of my beanstalk instance when calling the Parse Server with

curl -X GET -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX"   -H "Content-Type: application/json"  https://my-name.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/parse/classes/GameScore

But anytime I run this I get a:
curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name error.

So I figured I might now need to start point my requests at the domain name I purchased? Or possibly the load balancer?

Do you see anything wrong with this setup?

I saw a very similar question here [Setting up Elastic Beanstalk application with HTTPS](https://serverfault.com/questions/712774/setting-up-elastic-beanstalk-application-with-https)

and like this person, my domain is just timing out right now. The given answer didn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Yes, you'd want to point `curl` at the URL the SSL certificate is for. Or add `-k` to the cURL call to skip SSL verification.

Comment: So in my old curl I can pass parameters and headers. If I change the curl URL to be 

curl -X GET -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX" -H "Content-Type: application/json" my-domain.com/parse/classes/GameScore would this correctly get it to the /parse/classes/GameScore route on the actual EB server without changing the headers or any included parameters?

Comment: Wow. I just tried it and it worked! Was not expecting that. Thanks for the quick help.